# How do I remove all of the rows (from my query) matching one ID if one of those rows has a non null value in a field?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

So basically, I have a few tables, and I need to get certain records in one query. The code below is working. However Id like to add a new functionally.

In ESP_Facturacao, there might duplicate rows for the same Item_TAG.
If one is null, and the other is not, I will get the null record on my query.

(((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Null)

I would like to not have any duplicate records with the same Item_TAG, and to remove any rows with an Item_TAG that already had a record with a  non null 1a_MesAno.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

```
SELECT
ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID,
ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno] AS Data,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_Faturado] AS Valor,
'1 a' AS Tarefa,
'1' AS Control,
'1' AS Estado,
ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG,
ESP_SubTipo.Descrição AS SubTipo,
ESP_Unidade.Descricao AS Unidade,
ESP_Facturacao.ID
FROM (ESP_Unidade INNER JOIN ((ESP_TAG LEFT JOIN ESP_Facturacao ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Facturacao.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN (ESP_SubTipo INNER JOIN ESP_Fisico ON ESP_SubTipo.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID) ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Tag_ID) ON ESP_Unidade.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID) INNER JOIN ESP_Administrativas ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Administrativas.ESP_Tag_ID
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Null) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Novo_Pos_2010)=True));
```

Comment: I have read somewhere that I can do a select within a select. but I have no clue how to do that.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT
ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID,
ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID,
ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno] AS Data,
ESP_Facturacao.[1a_Faturado] AS Valor,
'1 a' AS Tarefa,
'1' AS Control,
'1' AS Estado,
ESP_SubTipo.Descrição AS SubTipo,
ESP_Unidade.Descricao AS Unidade,
ESP_Facturacao.ID

FROM ESP_Unidade INNER JOIN (((ESP_TAG LEFT JOIN ESP_Facturacao ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Facturacao.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN (ESP_SubTipo INNER JOIN ESP_Fisico ON ESP_SubTipo.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_SubTipo_ID) ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Tag_ID) INNER JOIN ESP_Administrativas ON ESP_TAG.ID = ESP_Administrativas.ESP_Tag_ID) ON ESP_Unidade.ID = ESP_Fisico.ESP_Unidade_ID
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG) Not In (SELECT ESP_Facturacao.Item_TAG
FROM ESP_Facturacao
WHERE (((ESP_Facturacao.[1a_MesAno]) Is Not Null)))) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Data_Aut_Funcion) Is Null) AND ((ESP_Administrativas.Novo_Pos_2010)=True));
```